# Generate Apk gives erron in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I try to generate an apk however it gives me an error on Command Prompt:*

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
>
>   > 1 exception was raised by workers:   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
>   >     jarsigner: key associated with my-key-alias not a private key
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

*Anyone can help me about this error ?*

Comment: did u fix this?, having the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you previously were building a bundle release with different keystore, please do clean before.

Launching `./gradlew clean` shall help.